# Conexión sql server c# genera un error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando hacer una conexion con sql server con c# de la siguiente manera

```
cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-0FVQPKK\SEBASTIAN;Initial Catalog=FUCS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=usuario;Password=contrasena");
```

definiendo el cn como  " `SqlConnection cn;`"

pero me genera un error con el

> DESKTOP-0FVQPKK\SEBASTIAN

no se como definir bien mi conexion, este codigo ya me habia funcionado en otra ocacion pero el Data Source era diferente

Comment: Cuál es el mensaje de error que le arroja?

Comment: El error es basicamente por el " \ "

Comment: Debe tener cuidado con los caracteres de escape, \ es uno de ellos para resolver reemplazar por el doble  \\

Comment: Solo una sugerencia adicional. Debes guardar la cadena de conexión en un archivo de configuración (web.config / app.config) y no dejarla directamente en el código.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No puede usar `\` porque es el inicio de una secuencia de escape , según la documentación para tener el doble backlash  sería `\\`
[Secuencias de Escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-PE/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Su cadena de conexión quedaría así

```
cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-0FVQPKK\\SEBASTIAN;Initial Catalog=FUCS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=usuario;Password=contrasena");
 /* O ASÍ */
cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-0FVQPKK\SEBASTIAN;Initial Catalog=FUCS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=usuario;Password=contrasena");
```

Comment: GRACIAS YA FUNCIONA :D

Answer (score 3):

Si vas a usar el nombre del servidor tal cual DESKTOP-0FVQPKK\SEBASTIAN
Deeberias agregar una @ al inicio de la cadena antes de las "".

tu cadena quedaria asi:

```
cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-0FVQPKK\SEBASTIAN;Initial Catalog=FUCS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=usuario;Password=contrasena");
```